# Why is it thread-safe to perform lazy initialization in python?

Tags: python, concurrency

I just read this [blog post](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2008/08/lazy-descriptors.html) about a recipe to lazily initialize an object property.
I am a recovering java programmer and if this code was translated into java, it would be considered a race condition (double check locking). Why does it work in python ? I know there is a threading module in python. Are locks added surreptitiously by the interpreter to make this thread-safe?

How does canonical thread-safe initialisation look in Python?

Comment: @NiklasB. You should make that an answer.

Comment: Who told you it worked? When it comes to threading, you should never trust a naive test... ;)

Comment: @qarma: what exactly is missing from the accepted answer? What concerns should be addressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, no locks are added automatically.
2. That's why this code is *not* thread-safe.
3. If it seems to work in a multi-threaded program without problems, it's probably due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which makes the hazard less likely to occur.

Comment: So it works in Cython because of the GIL. But this code would break in Jython. Ok, got it.

Comment: @BonAmi: CPython, not Cython. Cython is something else completely. But that's the general idea; it should work in CPython but it'd be a bad idea to depend on it in any case.

Comment: @NiklasB.: your new wording is much, much improved, thanks for that edit. :-) I found this because of the somewhat quizzical bounty placed on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I didn't notice there is a bounty. Thanks for pointing out the short-comings of this (very old) answer of mine

Answer (score 5):

This code is not thread-safe.

### Determining thread safety

You could check thread-safety by stepping through the bytecode, like:

```
from dis import dis

dis('a = [] \n'
    'a.append(5)')
# Here you could see that it's thread safe
##  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
##              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
##
##  2           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
##              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
##             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
##             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
##             18 POP_TOP
##             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
##             22 RETURN_VALUE

dis('a = [] \n'
    'a += 5')
# And this one isn't (possible gap between 15 and 16)
##  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
##              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
##
##  2           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
##              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
##             12 BUILD_LIST               1
##             15 BINARY_ADD
##             16 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
##             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
##             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, I should warn, that bytecode could change over time and thread-safety could depend on python you use (cpython, jython, ironpython etc)

So, general recommendation, if you ever need thread-safety, use synchronization mechanisms: Locks, Queues, Semaphores, etc.

### Thread-safe version of LazyProperty

Thread-safety for descriptor you've mentioned, could be brought like this:

```
from threading import Lock

class LazyProperty(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self.__name__ = func.__name__
        self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        self._lock = Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if obj is None: return None
        # __get__ may be called concurrently
        with self.lock:
            # another thread may have computed property value
            # while this thread was in __get__
            # line below added, thx @qarma for correction
            if self.__name__ not in obj.__dict__: 
                # none computed `_func` yet, do so (under lock) and set attribute
                obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self._func(obj)
        # by now, attribute is guaranteed to be set,
        # either by this thread or another
        return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
```

### Canonical thread-safe initialization

For a canonical thread-safe initialization, you need to code a metaclass, which acquires lock at creation time, and releases after the instance has been created:

```
from threading import Lock

class ThreadSafeInitMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        # here we add lock to !!class!! (not instance of it)
        # class could refer to its lock as: self.__safe_init_lock
        # see namespace mangling for details
        namespace['_{}__safe_init_lock'.format(name)] = Lock()
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        lock = getattr(cls, '_{}__safe_init_lock'.format(cls.__name__))
        with lock:
            retval = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return retval


class ThreadSafeInit(metaclass=ThreadSafeInitMeta):
    pass

######### Use as follows #########
# class MyCls(..., ThreadSafeInit):
#     def __init__(self, ...):
#         ...
##################################

'''
class Tst(ThreadSafeInit):
    def __init__(self, val):
        print(val, self.__safe_init_lock)
'''
```

### Something completely different from metaclasses solution

And finally, if you need simpler solution, just create common init lock and create instances using it:

```
from threading import Lock
MyCls._inst_lock = Lock()  # monkey patching | or subclass if hate it
...
with MyCls._inst_lock:
   myinst = MyCls()
```

However, it's easy to forget which may bring a very interesting debugging times.
Also possible to code a class decorator, but in my opinion, it would be no better, than metaclass solution.

Comment: Will the metaclass method work correctly for derived classes too? I mean, if there's `A->B->meta`, will `__new__` get "A" or "B" for `name`?

Comment: @qarma yes, it will. And every created subclass would have its own version of `__safe_init_lock` as expected

Comment: Cool. I think this writeup is still missing one step, if it were applied to original question. Consider `LazyProperty` in the linked blog post, AFAIK there's no way to ensure that `__get__` is only called once, thus the trick is to protect computation and attribute assignment inside the `__get__` method, right?

Comment: @qarma actually it's tricky part of python's inheritance: when you use .dot qualification, it kicks off a new search ( instance -> class -> class' parent -> etc..) So as long as first occurence is found, further search process is stopped. And when you set the same attribute in instance and then try to get it, you'll get exactly the one set in instance.
You may try to add print trace to descriptor, and I promise it'll be printed only once

Comment: @qarma but you're right, `__get__` could be possibly invoked by concurrent threads __roughly at the same time__, that's why we use lock to ensure it's thread safe

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @thodnev's answer, here's how to protect lazy **property** initialisation:

```
class LazyProperty(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self.__name__ = func.__name__
        self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if obj is None: return None
        # __get__ may be called concurrently
        with self.lock:
            # another thread may have computed property value
            # while this thread was in __get__
            if self.__name__ not in obj.__dict__:
                # none computed `_func` yet, do so (under lock) and set attribute
                obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self._func(obj)
        # by now, attribute is guaranteed to be set,
        # either by this thread or another
        return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
```

Comment: Oh, I've initially missed it, now added to answer

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/71816862/4619958 seems faster :)

Answer (score 0):

A more performant solution based on @DimaTisnek: (See comments for reasons)

```
class LazyProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self.__name__ = func.__name__
        self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if obj is None:
            return None

        # if the value is already there, we do not need to fetch the lock
        # for example, suppose `self.a` is already there but `self.b` is not. Then it can happen that
        # `self.b` is slowly initializing, occupying the lock, while someone calls `self.a`.
        # Without this additional `if`, the `self.a` will block until `self.b` finishes initializing,
        # which is unnecessarily slow.
        if self.__name__ not in obj.__dict__:
            # __get__ may be called concurrently
            with self.lock:
                # another thread may have computed property value
                # while this thread was in __get__
                if self.__name__ not in obj.__dict__:
                    # none computed `_func` yet, do so (under lock) and set attribute
                    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self._func(obj)

        # by now, attribute is guaranteed to be set,
        # either by this thread or another
        return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
```

---

Another version:

```
class LazyGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self._data_map = {}
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def get(self, obj):
        # if the value is already there, we do not need to fetch the lock
        # for example, suppose `self.a` is already there but `self.b` is not. Then it can happen that
        # `self.b` is slowly initializing, occupying the lock, while someone calls `self.a`.
        # Without this additional `if`, the `self.a` will block until `self.b` finishes initializing,
        # which is unnecessarily slow.
        if obj not in self._data_map:
            with self.lock:
                # another thread may have computed property value
                # while this thread was in __get__
                if obj not in self._data_map:
                    # none computed `_func` yet, do so (under lock) and set attribute
                    self._data_map[obj] = self._func(obj)

        # by now, attribute is guaranteed to be set,
        # either by this thread or another
        return self._data_map[obj]
```

Comment: Unlocked read is a valid optimisation; then again, if you are optimising for the "already initialised" case, why not `try: return obj.__dict__[self.__name__] except KeyError: ...`?

Comment: @DimaTisnek Good idea :) Just not sure whether the exception will be expensive

Comment: 1. no it won't; 2. test it ;-)

Comment: "Another version" will suffer from memory leaks because of `self._data_map = {}` which should instead be initialized as a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()` (see Brett Slatkin's *Effective Python, 2nd ed*, p. 194 for details)